# Create browser controls like ActiveX in Java?

Tags: java, browser, applet, activex, multiplatform

I'd like to know if it is possible create browser controls in Java?

On my web site, I want to read the MAC address of visitor's Ethernet (or wifi) card, and then submit it to a PHP script. Now we have a ActiveX control which works perfectly, but it only works on Windows, so we are searching for something multi-platform. So we are thinking about using Java (all users are supposed to have already installed JRE).

Is Java Applet the only alternative solution? Any suggestions?

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, I think Java Applet is the only solution.

How about Flash? But I'm not sure whether ActionScript can read the MAC address.